# gcloud VM instance template throws "docker run executable file not found in $PATH" but starting manually via SSH works

Tags: docker, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-instance-template

I'm trying to create 2 instance groups with 1 single VM that has write/read permissions to a mounted disk and several others that can only read.

In all of these VM's i'm running neo4j community via docker.

My main issue is configuring the instance group template to properly start & wether to persist or not persist OS disk for this use case.

If I manually SSH into the VM and run `docker run -p7474:7474 neo4j` etc. The container starts and I can access the DB from the internet directly as well as through the HTTPS load balancer I have configured to point towards it.

However, the configuration added in the instance group template always fails to start the container.

My current config for the "Host Directory mounts:

Mount path: `/data`, Host Path: `data`, Mode: `Read/write`

Docker command:

`docker run neo4j`

arguments:

- `-p 7474:7474`
- `-p 7472:7473`
- `-p 7687:7687`
- `-v $HOME/neo4j/data:/data`

However this results in

```
\\\docker run\\\ executable file not found in $PATH
```

Any advice on properly configuring this is appreciated.
I'm particularly interested if in this scenario -- is there any point in persisting the OS disk?

Surely the docker image configurations should be enough, and the attached "Host Directory mount" should persist the database's data appropriately.

Comment: Show the startup script that is running Docker. The path for startup scripts is not the same as your user identity. Therefore either modify the path or specify that absolute path to Docker.

Comment: How do you call your docker command in the instance template?

Comment: Guys this one is totally on me, I was using the built-in interface to override the container start commend itself, not the VM command that's supposed to start the container. I fixed it and all works well now, I'll post another issue on the port-forwarding not working from my load-balancer to that VM instance group.